Facing problems creating script on Apps Script for creating folders with upload images from Forms, renaming the folders with the first answer
guys! I'm pretty new to code.gs, and I need some advice to writing a script.
My company needs to validate some customer information, and the criteria requires us to have photo evidence of said information.
I already set up the Forms with the questions:
1 - Client ID (every client has a registration ID)
2 - Image upload (A upload-type question for us to upload the photo evidence).
Is there a way to create a folder, containing the images sent, named after the client's ID so we can sort them out faster?

Is there a way to create a folder, containing the images sent, named after the client's ID so we can sort them out faster? This is possible with Google Apps Script. Upload files to Google Drive from Google Forms is a sample that you can modify aside from the linked duplicate.
